# How to Access a text file on blackberry 10 using native SDK

Tags: qt4, filesystems, blackberry-10, qfile

Inside a folder called Resources I have a text file called "hello.txt". How do I read it using blackberry 10 native sdk using cpp. 
I found something like using a FileConnection. But its showing FileConnection is not declared!!. Is there any header file required??
Please mind that I am using cpp:

```
FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("Resources/hello.txt", Connector.READ);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you get FileConnection from the BlackBerry JDE API, or from one of the BB 10 APIs? It doesn't turn up in a search of the BB 10 native API documents, I suspect you were reading the JDE documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use QFile and QTextStream classes to read or write from files.

```
QFile file("app/native/assets/text.txt");
if (file.exists()) {
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        QTextStream textStream(&file);
        QString text = textStream.readAll();
        file.close();
    }
} else {
    qDebug() << "File doesn't exist";
}
```

Here, readAll() would return whole content of the stream. You can use readLine() method if you want to read only few length of content.